# jquery animation to change text of radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to introduce animation and change the text inside a div tag and also text against  radio buttons

Am able to change the text of the div with animation 
However I am not able to change the text against the radio with animation

NOTE - without animation I was able to do this based on an earlier question I had asked

Here is what I have as HTML:

```
<div id="questionBlock">        
    <article>loremipsum dah blah blah </article>
</div>

<label class="block" id="lblFirstOption" for = "sizeSmall"> 
    <input type = "radio" name = "radSize" id = "sizeSmall" value = "small" />small
</label>
```

The Jquery that works for the simple div :

```
$('#questionBlock article').fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).text(val["carType"]).fadeIn().delay(3000);
});
```

The Jquery that is not working for the label text change with animation:

```
$('#sizeSmall')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue.fadeOut(function() {
    $(this)[0].nextSibling.nodeValue(val["carType"]).fadeIn().delay(3000);
});
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.nodeValue is not a function, you just set it with an assignment

```
$(this)[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = val["carType"];
```

Also the since you are now using the actual DOM object you are no longer in the jQuery chain, so chaining fadeIn and delay after the call will fail. Even if you were still in the jQuery chain you cannot fadeIn/Out textNodes. You would need to wrap the text in another element like span

HTML

```
<label class="block" id="lblFirstOption" for = "sizeSmall"> 
    <input type = "radio" name = "radSize" id = "sizeSmall" value = "small" />
    <span>small</span>
</label>
```

js

```
$('#sizeSmall').next().fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).text(val["cartype"]).fadeIn().delay(3000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#lblFirstOption span').fadeOut(function() {      
   $(this).parent().append('<span>TestRadio</span>').fadeIn().delay(3000);
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zL51qa7k/)

Comment: thanks - this worked too - accepting Patrick's answer as it came in first - thank you

Comment: @eXamScripts , I had given answer first not patrick,however if you want to give patrick answer priority ,its your wish.

Comment: oops - sorry when I see the timestamp - yours does show as 8:27 and Patricks at 8:28 - so yes you are correct - not sure how I goofed up - my apologies